# Kill Command for a jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

Hey I am looking for a kill command for my app that lets me kill other apps. I want my app to be able to kill other apps while my app is in the background. I found this kill command:

```
Class $SBApplicationController = objc_getClass("SBApplicationController")
SBApplication *app = [[$SBApplicationController sharedInstance]
                         applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:displayIdentfier]; 
if (app) 
    [app kill];
```

The only problem is it seems to only work for Mac OSX and I am trying to do this on my jailbroken iPhone so I need iOS. I was wondering if anybody knew of a kill command that can do this? Or is there any way to convert this kill command from Mac OSX to iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused. SBApplicationController is an iOS-specific class; it doesn't exist on Mac OS X.

Comment: Oh ok. So if I used NsArray to get the process Ids. how do I get this kill command to work with my project?the problem I kept having was trying to implement a springBoard framework into my project. so how would I go about implementing this into my project?