# Kill Command for a jailbroken iPhone(iOS X)

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kill Command for a jailbroken iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963640/kill-command-for-a-jailbroken-iphone)

Hey I am looking for a kill command that lets my app kill other apps while my app is running in the background. I am building my app on a jailbroken iPhone so I am looking for one that will work with the iOS X platform. Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You,
rytime

Comment: Please DO NOT post the same question twice on StackOverflow. Your question will appear in the suggested questions box for users, as well as in the unanswered tab. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3):

There is `killall`, which will kill an application by it's binary's name, or there is `kill` which will kill by a process ID. Are either of those what you want?

Example usage:

```
NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"killall %@", executableName];
system([exec UTF8String]);
```

---

```
NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kill %i", processId];
system([exec UTF8String]);
```

Comment: yes that sounds great! I used nsArray to get both the process ID and the actual name. so if you could share those that would be great

Comment: I added some example usages, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If your app isn't made especially for that purpose then you shouldn't do this without the user knowing it. You can either use `"killall executableName"` in a `system()` command or if you are developing for MobileSubstrate then you could hook some SpringBoard classes and close the SBApplication/remove the SBApplicationIcon from the switcher which will also close the corresponding SBApplication.

Comment: ok how would I use the killall("executableName") command? do I have to have the executable or just the name of the app?

Comment: The info.plist of every app contains a value for CFBundleExecutable. You need to grab all those values with a for loop, convert them to a char and then execute the commant with the char

Comment: ok so how do I find the info.plist? also how do I execute with a char?

Comment: The info.plist is located in every .app bundle in the /Applications and in the /var/mobile/Applications directory. Use for loops, NSFileManager contentsAtDirectory and some if statements to get to the Infi.plist of every app. Initialize a NSDictionary with contents at the path of info.plist and take the value for CFBundleExecutable. Then do system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"killall %@",executableName"] UTF8String]); that will kill the process.