# Kill processes programmatically with iOS app? (Example in App Store)

Tags: ios, memory, process

I am rather confused about how this would be possible with the iOS Sandbox, but there appears to be an app in the App Store that does this: [Dual Core System Activity Monitor for iPhone 4S](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dual-core-system-activity/id490435730?mt=8)

According to the [Developer Website](http://recessionapps.com/System2.html) this app can:

> Stop Apps:
>   Use the Stop Apps button to quickly free up memory. Tap the button and dismiss the dialog multiple times to free up additional memory each time. You do not actually need to double press the Home button to kill the apps.

I am able to get a list of processes running with their pid's. How could I "free up memory" by, I assume, killing processes or other apps?

Note: While I intend to submit this particular project for the App Store, I would still be interested to know how this is done on a jailbroken phone, if that's your specialty. Plus I'm sure other programmers reading this could benefit from such knowledge as well.

Comment: Also, that behavior would be AWFUL because there'd be no way to follow Apple's provided willTerminate: chain, which allows apps to clean themselves (and their users' data) up before termination.

Comment: You can use the killall command similar to macs:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963856/kill-command-for-a-jailbroken-iphoneios-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a scam app ..it's iOS's duty to terminate processes if you need more memory.

You could read the list of processes and then virtually terminate them (remove them from a table view or something) but not actually terminate the process itself.

Comment: I guess that is a possibility but you'd think Apple would catch that.

Comment: there are a lot of scam apps in the app store..mainly of locate-a-cell-phone-number variety .If anything it's categorized wrong..but that's developer's job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is claiming a lot of memory (be still below the threshold) so that iOS kills of other running apps. While shortly after releasing the memory.